# PDO insert multiple rows with key and values as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hardcode

my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Matrix
            [1] => Ryan 
        )

    [surname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Relaoded
            [1] => Lose
        )

)
```

my problem is that, the key and value doesn't match the count.

How to insert this array like exact structure to mysql with PDO?

In mysql table

```
    ----------------------------------
   |    id      name      surname    |
   |    1       Matrix    Relaoded   |
   |    2       Ryan      Lose       | 
    ----------------------------------
```

of course i need solution **programmatically**.

I spent hours, to go trought this awesome forum, but i can't find solution :(

Thanks ;)

Comment: `"key and value doesn't match the count."` - what do you mean?

Comment: `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?,?,?);`

then:
`for i = 0; i < count($['name']) {`
`execute(i+1,$a['name'][i],$a['surname'][i])`
`}`

Comment: As a first step - forget you have PDO and database - just try to `echo` the information in the similar way. Could you do that?

Comment: `foreach($arr['name'] as $key => $name) { $surname = $arr['surname'][$key]; }`

Comment: Loop through `$array['name']`, get the corresponding `$array['surname']` value, then insert them.

Comment: @Your Common Sense thats because values is as array :D

Comment: @zerkms yes thanks for opinion, but i always do that ;)

Comment: @beater: you always do *what*? If you can `echo` the variables in a correct form - what is the **exact** issue with PDO you have then?

Answer (score 2):

@Zerkms was right, you need just to learn how to handle this array.
Easiest way would be

```
foreach($array['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $surname = $array['surname'][$key];
    // now you can use the pair
    var_dump($name,$surname);
}
```

Comment: thx, i have another question, how to insert this solution in mysql with PDO usin only one query

Comment: Now my code looks like this: http://codepad.org/E5fnuSCq


it's only insert last foreach values in 2 equialent rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`id`,`name`,`surname`) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

then the following pseudocode:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($['name']); $i++) {
    $db->execute($i+1, $a['name'][$i], $a['surname'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: I would have had to to use `$key=>$value` and use the `$key` to get the surname. It seemed less logical given you were looping round two arrays. If surnames was longer it's easier to write `$i < count($['name']) || $ i < count($a['surname'])`.

If it was the reverse (rows then columns) I would have used `foreach` because it's much neater.